# Use button function to open file browser and display image files

Tags: button, tkinter, appjar

I am totally new to Python and I am having some trouble figuring out how to open and display an image file from the file browser. I tried to use appJar and Tkinter. 
From Tkinter, I can select the image file, but the iamge will not be displayed.
From appJar, I just have no clue on how to use the button to open the file browser. 
Here I attached the code, I wonder if anyone is able to help me. Thanks.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter.messagebox import showinfo
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfile 



def popup_bonus():
    win = tk.Toplevel()
    win.wm_title("Window")


    a = ttk.Button(win, text="Open")
    a.grid(row=0, column=0)


    b = ttk.Button(win, text="Exit", command=win.destroy)
    b.grid(row=1, column=0)

def popup_showinfo():
    showinfo("About", "My Name, Python Version")

class Application(ttk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack()

        self.button_bonus = ttk.Button(self, text="File", command=popup_bonus)
        self.button_bonus.pack()

        self.button_showinfo = ttk.Button(self, text="Help", command=popup_showinfo)
        self.button_showinfo.pack()

root = tk.Tk()

app = Application(root)

root.mainloop()
```

## And this is the code using appJar

```
#import the library
from appJar import gui
import os

#create a GUI variable called app
app = gui('Window', '400x200')
app.setBg('silver')


#habdle button events
def press(button):
    if button == 'About':
        app.infoBox(title = 'About', message = 'Python Verison, Author')

    if button == 'Exit':
        app.stop()

    if button == 'Open':
        app.openBox(title=None, dirName=None, fileTypes=[('images', '*.png'), ('images', '*.jpg')], asFile=True, parent=None, multiple=False, mode='w')

# add & configure widgets - widgets get a name,to help referencing
app.setFont(size=18, family='Calibri', underline=False)
app.addLabel('title', 'File Select')
app.setLabelBg('title', 'grey')
app.setLabelFg('title','black')


# link the buttons to the function called press
fileMenu = ['Open','-','Exit']
helpMenu = ['About']

app.addMenuList('File', fileMenu, press)
app.addMenuList('Help', helpMenu, press)


# start the GUI
app.go()
```

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

In appJar, you will need to add a button the GUI, that runs the function you've defined, when it's pressed:
`app.addButton('Open', press)`

That will cause the `openBox` to be shown.

Then, in your function, you need to capture the return value of the `openBox()` function (the image path) so that you can display it:

```
filename = app.openBox('Select Image')
app.addImage('img', filename)
```